# I could not connect .In cosole 'No connection' is showing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**this is my server.js**

**I could not able to connect my  mongodb atlas with my node js application.**
**this is error**

```
(node:15596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 65.1.118.236:27017 closed
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Himanshu\tinder-clone\tinder-backened\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:845:32)
at C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Himanshu\tinder-clone\tinder-backened\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:345:10    
at C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Himanshu\tinder-clone\tinder-backened\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Himanshu\tinder-clone\tinder-backened\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Himanshu\tinder-clone\tinder-backened\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1135:10)
at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Himanshu\tinder-clone\tinder-backened\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:344:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Himanshu\tinder-clone\tinder-backened\server.js:13:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)

const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const Card=require('./dbCards');

const app=express();
const port=process.env.PORT || 9000;

const conn="mongodb+srv://hhimanshu:hemant@cluster0.y18xj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(conn,{
useCreateIndex:true,
useNewUrlParser:true,
useUnifiedTopology:true,
}).then(()=>{
console.log("connection established");
}).catch((err)=>{
console.log("No Connection");
})



app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
res.status(200).send("Hello Himanshu")
});




app.post('/tinder/card',async(req,res)=>{
try{
    const user=new Card(req.body);
    const createUser=await user.save();
    console.log(createUser);
    res.status(201).send(createUser);
 
 }catch(e){
     res.status(400).send(e);
 }
})



app.get('/tinder/card',async(req, res)=>{
try{
    const studentsData=await Card.find();
    res.send(studentsData);
}catch(e){
    res.status(400).send(e);
}
})


app.listen(port,()=>{
console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**This is my dbCard.js**

```
 const mongoose=require('mongoose');
 const express=require('express');

 const cardSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
imgUrl:String
});

const Card=new mongoose.model('Card',cardSchema);

module.exports=Card;
```